# How can I specify that only certain platforms be available when creating a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with about 2 dozen related projects, all of which need to build for the 'x64' platform. They are all C# projects, but building them with 'AnyCPU' or 'x86' platforms gives us memory limitations that we can't live with (max of 4GB). When I create a new project I can use the Configuration Manager to switch it to 'x64', but it ads the 'AnyCPU' platform to the solution again and the project itself has 'AnyCPU' as well as x86.

How can I tell Visual Studio that I only want the 'x64' platform in new projects (or better yet, new projects in this solution)?

Comment: This is about changing defaults for new projects, not changing current configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer a couple days later. In Visual Studio 2015 navigate through the GUI to find this check box.

**Tools \ Options \ Projects and Solutions \ Web Projects \ "Use the 64-bit version of IIS Express for web sites and project"**

This enables use of 64-bit IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

Do this configuration changes in your solution properties. Right click on solution -> properties -> Configuration section and change the platform and save the file.

You can as well do the same thing by selecting your solution and press `F4` and select/change `Active Config`

[image]